Cannot launch Android Virtual Devices (avds) in Android Studio
Launching AVDs from both android studio and via the cli "emulator" command fails.
(the emulator did launch successfully on one single occasion)
Steps taken:

Create a pixel 6 avd
Install system image
Select avd from device manager
System tray reads "Starting avd" emulator window reads "connecting to emulator"
Emulator does not launch.

Attempted fixes:

Wiped avd data "wipe data"
Cold booting avd "cold boot"
Toggle "emulated performance" between "Hardware", "Software" and "Automatic"
Delete and reinstall avds
kill adb server with "kill server"
Attempt to launch via emulator cli command emulator -list-avds returns:
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-skyjuice/emu-crash-34.2.13.db, detection is enabled for process: 5302
Uninstall and reinstall Android Studio
Add /sdk, /platform-tools, /emulator, tools/bin, to my PATH

Android emulator, sdk 14, android SDK build tools, Android SDK Platform tools are all installed in android studio.
idea.log
2024-05-09 16:10:02,713 [ 142492]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 - Not yet booted
2024-05-09 16:10:05,650 [ 145429]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 - Displaychange event: 0
2024-05-09 16:10:05,650 [ 145429]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 - Display notification event: event: DISPLAY_CONFIGURATIONS_CHANGED_UI displayConfigurationsChangedNotification { displayConfigurations { displays { width: 1080 height: 2400 dpi: 420 } userConfigurable: 3 maxDisplays: 11 } }
2024-05-09 16:10:05,652 [ 145431]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.streaming.emulator.EmulatorView - Received notification: event: DISPLAY_CONFIGURATIONS_CHANGED_UI displayConfigurationsChangedNotification { displayConfigurations { displays { width: 1080 height: 2400 dpi: 420 } userConfigurable: 3 maxDisplays: 11 } }
2024-05-09 16:10:15,642 [ 155421]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.streaming.emulator.EmulatorController - android.emulation.control.EmulatorController/streamNotification call failed - UNAVAILABLE: Network closed for unknown reason
2024-05-09 16:10:15,642 [ 155421]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.streaming.emulator.EmulatorController - android.emulation.control.EmulatorController/streamScreenshot call failed - UNAVAILABLE: Network closed for unknown reason
2024-05-09 16:10:15,644 [ 155423]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.streaming.emulator.EmulatorController - Disconnected from Pixel 6 (5554)
2024-05-09 16:10:15,724 [ 155503]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 - Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11:SIGSEGV)
2024-05-09 16:10:15,724 [ 155503]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 6 - Emulator terminated with exit code 139
2024-05-09 16:10:15,897 [ 155676]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.adb.AdbService - Device [emulator-5554] is offline
2024-05-09 16:10:26,642 [ 166421]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2024-05-09 16:10:41,411 [ 181190]   INFO - #c.i.u.t.DateFormatUtil - cannot load system formats (JNA=true), resorting to JRE for en_US
2024-05-09 16:11:18,215 [ 217994]   WARN - #c.i.o.a.ActionStub - ActionGroup should be registered using <group> tag: id="Android.CreateResourcesActionGroup" class="org.jetbrains.android.actions.CreateResourceFileActionGroup"
2024-05-09 16:11:18,560 [ 218339]   WARN - #c.i.i.a.CopyTBXReferenceAction - Cannot find TBX tool for IDE: AndroidStudio
2024-05-09 16:11:36,265 [ 236044]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2024-05-09 16:11:36,313 [ 236092]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=Greeting Card, containerState=COMPONENT_CREATED, componentStore=/home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/GreetingCard)KotlinCommonCompilerArguments took 11 ms


System
Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1
archlinux - android-studio installed via AUR

Consider reading this post. Besides that you can check system resources and increase emulator memory.

I think the "Storing crashdata" is just informing you that's where it will be logged. This happens for me also despite still being able to launch. Are you using the correct flags? e.g., emulator -avd Pixel_8_Pro_API_30_Android_11_ replacing the name with your avds name.

Do you have the correct paths configured in your .bashrc (or .zshrc)?
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools```

I have the same problem with Jellyfish on Windows 10. It appears with all my AVDs, and even after wiping them or creating a new one.
I often see the following window. In the details, it says something like
Crash reason:  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION_WRITE
Crash address: 0x0

This does not help me a lot ...


It's comment, not an answer

Part One
"Show on Disk" from the avd device manager revealed the avd's were being created in .config/.android/avd.
Set the ANDROID_AVD_HOME environment variable to that location.
~/.bash_profile
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME="~/.config/.android/avd"
After I was able to successfully run an avd with emulator -avd Pixel_6 -gpu host
Part two:
Switched the avd's "Emulated Performance" to "Graphics: Hardware"
All avds now work without issues.
